# Passing an object as attribute to compiled directive on the fly

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have a angular element on the page which needs to communicate with the rest of the non angular page elements.

I am creating directive elements on the fly, and appending it to its target div. I am trying to pass that created directive an object (ajax object), which contains just attributes.

The issue is that I can't figure out how to pass just this ajax object to the directive, as $compile requires a scope. When the http finishes, and because i have to use `=` in the directive, the directives are being over-ridden.

Please see my plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/brTWgUWTotI44tECZXlQ ( sorry about the images ). Click the `<button>` to trigger the directive.

```
(function() {
'use strict';
var CHANNEL = 'podOverlay';
angular.module('CavernUI', [])
  .controller('CavernCtrl', function($scope,getItemService) {

    $scope.model = {};
    var _pods = $scope.model.pods = {};

    function getData(selector) {
      $(selector).each(function(i, pod) {
        _pods[+pod.dataset.item] = {
          $: $(pod)
        };
      });

      Object.keys($scope.model.pods).map(function(key) {
        getItemService.getItem(key).success(function(response) {
          _pods[key] = angular.extend(_pods[key], response);
          $scope.$broadcast(CHANNEL, _pods[key], $scope);
        });
      })
    }

    $scope.runPodCheck = function(selector) {
      getData(selector);
    }
  })
  .directive('podchecker', function($compile) {
     
     var createOverlay = function(e,data,scope){
         scope.data = data;
         // can i just pass data rather than scope.data?
         // If I pass the scope, then when another $broadcast happens
         // the scope updates, wiping out the last scope change.
         // Scope here really needs to be a static object that's
         // created purely for the hand off. But I don't know if 
         // that can be done.
         angular.element(data.$[0]).empty().append($compile('<overlay data="data"></overlay>')(scope));
     }

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        check: '&',
      },
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      link: function(scope,elm,attr){
         scope.$on(CHANNEL,createOverlay);
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('overlay', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        o: '=data' // here is the problem. 
      },
      template: '<div class="overlay"><a href="{{o.url}}"><img ng-src="{{o.images.IT[0]}}"/></a></div>',
      link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
        
      }
    }
  })
  .service('getItemService', ['$http', function($http) {
    this.getItem = function(itemId) {
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://www.aussiebum.com/ajaxproc/item',
        params: {
          id: itemId,
          ajxop: 1
        },
      });
    };
  }]);
}());
```

Edits:
Expected ouput:
[image]

Comment: Is it required that you continue working with `non angular page elements` or you have the option to make them in angular?

Comment: Not quite understanding the problem, what is the expected result? `o.data` exists in the `overlay` linking function.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/pwEvVR9o6S77BXGt8JSM?p=preview when I tried, scope.o , it shows different objects for each directive .. may be I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Like the others have eluded, it is hard to understand what you're expected result should be. With that in mind, I have gathered that you are trying to read the "data-item" property from each DOM element and pass it to a directive to replace that element with another element. The problem is that when you try to do this, it always uses the "last" DOM element's "data-item" because it somehow gets overridden since all of the elements share the same scope. The desired result is a pair of RED underwear and a pair of BLUE underwear, based on the "data-item" value. Is this correct?

Comment: @LouieAlmeda yes it's a constraint. It's an admin tool that interacts with a "normal" html page. I can't wrap the whole thing in angular.

Comment: @BrentMCFerrin. You understand the question correctly. I have edited the question, and I hope it makes more sense. What I want is just a one time hand off of data to the `overlay` that has its associated server data. With using the scope, as you can see, the data is overwritten over each `$broadcast` so the `overlays` look the same, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure this is the best approach, but one way might be to manually create a new scope for each of the overlays.

So changed this:

```
var createOverlay = function(e,data,scope){
           scope.data = data;
           angular.element(data.$[0]).empty().append($compile('<overlay data="data"></overlay>')(scope));
       }
```

to this:

```
var createOverlay = function(e,data,scope){
           var overlayScope = scope.$new(false); // use true here for isolate scope, false to inherit from parent
           overlayScope.data = data;
           angular.element(data.$[0]).empty().append($compile('<overlay data="data"></overlay>')(overlayScope));
       }
```

Updated Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/wBQ1cqVKfSqwqf04SnPP

More info about [$new()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$new)

Cheers!

Comment: This does work. I was hoping though there was a way to "catch" the object passed from `podchecker` to the `overlay` rather than having to create a new scope. Later down the line I may need to the original `scope`.

Comment: Oh, just use `var overlayScope = scope.$new(false);` It should then inherit from the parent scope and access it's members using `$scope.$parent`